# object model wrong or bug in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

We have an object model like this one with InheritanceType.JOINED defined for BusinessPartner.

s. UML diagram: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/klassendiagramm.png/

InvoiceAccount  and PaymentAccount are definded as @Embedded (in Customer and Supplier)

The Problem is:

We would like to find all BusinessPartner with `bank = <definedBank>`

So we have built such HQL statement:

1.

```
"SELECT distinct p FROM BusinessPartner p  
WHERE (p.paymentAccount.bank= ?1 OR p.invoiceAccount.bank = ?1)
```

unfortunately Hibernate translates it in following (wrong?!) SQL stmt.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    p0_.id as id9_,  ... p0_.name as name2_9_, 
    CASE 
        WHEN p0_.id is not null 
        THEN 0 
        WHEN p0_1_.id is not null 
        THEN 1 
        WHEN p0_2_.id is not null 
        THEN 2 
        WHEN p0_3_.id is not null 
        THEN 3 
        WHEN p0_4_.id is not null 
        THEN 4 
    END as clazz_ 
FROM 
    BusinessPartner p0_ LEFT OUTER JOIN Supplier p0_1_ ON p0_.id= p0_1_.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN IndependentSupplier p0_2_ ON p0_.id= p0_2_.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN InHouseSupplier p0_3_ ON p0_.id= p0_3_.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Customer p0_4_ ON p0_.id= p0_4_.id 
WHERE 
    p0_1_.paymentaccount_bank_id= ? or p0_2_.invoiceaccount_bank_id= ?
```

we miss  in "where" the Customer part:  v0_4_.invoiceaccount_bank_id= ?

Is our object model wrong or is it a bug in Hibernate?